# What is the GetFullPath(String, String) overload?

Tags: c#, base-class-library

The documentation of the [Path.GetFullPath(String) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netframework-4.8) contains the following text (emphasis mine):

> **Important**
>
> If `path` is a relative path, this overload returns a fully qualified path that can be based on the current drive and current directory. [...] To return a deterministic path, call the **GetFullPath(String, String)** overload. [...]

I checked the documentation and IntelliSense, and I just can't find a GetFullPath overload that takes two parameters (.net 4.8, full classic framework). Is this a documentation bug (and maybe they meant `Path.Combine(String, String)` instead?) or did I miss something?

Comment: The documentation is clearly wrong, wasn't updated to reflect the changes, it should take you to the Core 3.0 [version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netcore-3.0#System_IO_Path_GetFullPath_System_String_System_String_) when clicking on the link under `Important`... section. They although did update the link to `IsPathFullyQualified`...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: I just checked: `IsPathFullyQualified` also links to the .net 4.8 doc, it's just that there is no .net 4.8 page for that, so it automatically gets redirected to the .net core 3 doc (see the pink banner at the top after clicking the link). I guess it doesn't work for `GetFullPath` because *the page itself* exists for .net 4.8.

Comment: Aha, good catch!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was introduced in .NET Core 2.1 / .NET Standard 2.1. It seems that the docs website isn't clever enough to hide parts of the documentation which are only relevant to newer .NET versions.

[See the docs for `GetFullPath(String, String)` here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netcore-3.0#System_IO_Path_GetFullPath_System_String_System_String_).

You can select which .NET Version to view the docs for in the top left:

[image: Screenshot of learn.microsoft.com version selector]

Comment: Why has this answer been down-voted? It is the correct answer to the question. The method is available in the System.Runtime.Extensions class in .NET Core 2.1